# IDE for python - creating GUI application for raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

i have a raspberry pi 2 and its GPIO camera.

i want to create a application with GUI to display the camera picture as well as to capture it with a button call "Snap" and do some processing with the image

is there any recommended IDE which i can use to easily create GUI like by drag and drop widgets instead of programming it

Comment: You could consider [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Use [Qt-Designer](http://doc.qt.io/) to create the windows (it is drag and drop, there is a Linux version also), and [pyuic4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) to convert the code to a python script. You can then import it and use it as you like ([various examples](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials)).

More examples: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/

Comment: Thanks Daniel . Will try it out .